# How can I make images not size outside of its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a container on a site that.
Inside this container I want 3 rows, each row has an image. The image itself it quite large, however I wanted to image to be restricted to the size of it's parent. How, even with a massive trail of `h-100`, the images when rendered are nearly 5 times the size of the viewport.

Here is my progress.

To clarify **I do not want the images to overflow, I need them all to shrink to not go outside the parent**

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x / Twitter-Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Body -->
<div id="main-container" style="opacity: 0.5;">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="position: fixed; bottom: 7%; height: 70vh;">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col h-100">
        <div class="row ">
          <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
        </div>

        <div class="row ">
          <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
          <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div class="row h-100">
  <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;" src="https://www.sepsis.org.nz/wp-content/uploads/placeholder.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
</div>
```

Comment: This only works for one image, the other two stack underneath it.

Comment: right, just append a class 'h-100' which gives the div a height. 
And set the style: 'max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;' tells the img to fit it's parent node

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

**use add this css property to image this way or externally as your preference.**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Head-->
<head>
    <style>
        img{
            overflow:hidden;
            object-fit:contain;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<!-- Body -->
<div id="main-container" style="opacity: 0.5;">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="position: fixed; bottom: 7%; height: 70vh;">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col h-100">
        <div class="row " style="overflow:hidden">
          <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
        </div>

        <div class="row ">
          <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
          <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight changes in HTML structure and added CSS.

```css
#img-wrapper {
  width: 300px; /* or in percentage*/
}

#img-main-row {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x / Twitter-Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Body -->
<div id="main-container" style="opacity: 0.5;">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="position: fixed; bottom: 7%; height: 70vh;">
        <div id="img-main-row" class="row h-100">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto"
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto"
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto"
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry to be specific I did not want the images to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .container-fluid .row {
            height: calc(100%/3) !important;
        }
        img {
            max-height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<!-- Body -->
<div id="main-container" style="opacity: 0.5;">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="position: fixed; bottom: 7%; height: 70vh;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row " style="overflow:hidden">
                    <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto"
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
                </div>

                <div class="row ">
                    <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto"
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
                </div>
                <div class="row ">
                    <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto"
                        src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The parent of the image (row) have no specific height to limit the image within it.
2. Set the max-height of the images to 100%.

Try this:

```
<style>
    .imgParent {
        height: 100px;
    }

    img {
        max-height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

And

```
<div class="row imgParent">
     <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
</div>
```

- If you want to keep the aspect ratio of images remove `width="100%" height="auto"` from images.

Answer (score 0):

I based the example on the fact that you wish to keep always the images width at a minimum width of 100%, if you dont want that, I can still change it.

### Process:

I added the class `overflow` to your `.col` div that contain all the row image.

Then the goal is to hide your image height with `overflow:hidden` and then centering image with `position:absolute` as below:

(You might have some problem with js as it is using `position:absolute` please provide working example for more.)

```css
.overflow{
 overflow:auto;
}
.overflow .row{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100%;
}

.overflow img{
  min-width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x / Twitter-Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Body -->
<div id="main-container" style="opacity: 0.5;">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="position: fixed; bottom: 7%; height: 70vh;">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col h-100 overflow">
        <div class="row">
          <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100" height="auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
        </div>

        <div class="row ">
          <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1820x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
        </div>
        <div class="row ">
          <img class="rounded-circle img-fluid" width="100%" height="auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1720x1080.png" style="border: .2rem solid #1a4579;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't want the images to overflow, I needed them to "shrink" to fit into the occupied row.

Comment: @Joe this way they will occupy alway the whole width without shrink. but overflow is necessary to keep the proportion. From the moment you added width:100, image will shrink